# Javafx + FXML + Accelerators --- Platform independence?

Tags: javafx, keyboard-shortcuts, multiplatform

Every tutorial about accelerators teaches how to use them FROM CODE, not from fxml files. There you'll learn how tu use the predefined KeyCombinations in order to achieve platform independence.

Now I wonder, if I write this in fxml:

```
<MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.save" >
    <accelerator>
       <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="Z" control="UP"meta="DOWN" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
    </accelerator>
</MenuItem>
```

which should APPLE+<kbd>S</kbd> on mac, and should be <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on windows,

this should also work right? (PS: I don't own a windows OS/PC)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Now it's as simple as:

```
<MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.save" accelerator="Shortcut+S"/>
```

where `Shortcut` means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on Windows or Linux and <kbd>Meta</kbd> on Mac.
[Here's some more information about `KeyCombination`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCombination.html).